# TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable when using nested_admin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have used the nested_admin to use Inlines to get a customized view at Admin Dashboard.

Here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Quizzes, Question, Answer, UsersAnswer, QuizTakers
import nested_admin

class AnswerInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Answer
    extra = 4
    max_num = 4
    
class QuestionInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Question
    inlines = [AnswerInline,]
    extra = 19
    
class QuizAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [QuestionInline,]
    
class UsersAnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UsersAnswer
    
class QuizTakersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UsersAnswerInline,]
    
    
admin.site.register(UsersAnswerInline)
admin.site.register(QuizTakers, QuizTakersAdmin)
admin.site.register(Quizzes, QuizAdmin)
```

And also included the path in the main urls.py:

```
    path('nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
```

But I am getting this error :

for model in model_or_iterable: TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

I removed this error by changing admin.site.register(UsersAnswerInline)
to admin.site.register(UsersAnswer) to register the model.